# How to get Latitude and Longitude of highways and roads in Google maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude, google-latitude

In my company, we use the Google maps API to geocode addresses to get the Latitude and Longitude. Fpor cities, it works fine. But when we have to find the Lat/Long of Highways/Roads, that doesn't have numbers. We have just the name/code of the address and the Kilometer/Mile location of it (I.e: BR-060 at 50 KM, or: Bandeirantes Highway at Mile 150).

I live in Brazil, so maybe the expressions we use didn't match, but I want to know if there's a way to find the lat/long of these addresses, cause we can't find them. We tried to look in Google's documentation with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that shows how the Google Autoocomplete API returns back the latitude and longitude

```js
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(street);

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location;
  document.getElementById("lat").value = place.lat();
  document.getElementById("lon").value = place.lng();
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places&dummy=.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="street" name="street" placeholder="street">
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="lat" placeholder="lat">
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="lon" placeholder="lon">
  <br>
</form>
```